# compare multiple strings in foreach

Tags: c#, razor

I am making some programming for a hotel. They want an email receipt if a booking has been made.

I am working with a razor mergefield called: `@GuaranteePolicy`

A guest can book 1 or multiple rooms. If there is booked multiple rooms, the GuaranteePolicy has to be set on each room. But if the GuaranteePolicy is the same on each room, I have to print the GuaranteePolicy in the footer.

So as I see it I have to compare all the GuaranteePolicy mergefields in each room, and see if they consist of the same text? That I do not know how to solve.

I loop through the multiple rooms, and print if the GuaranteePolicy is different. That is working fine:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(room.GuaranteePolicy))
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span><strong>GuaranteePolicy:</strong></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>@room.GuaranteePolicy</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
```

But how can I compare the text in multiple `room.GuaranteePolicy` and check if the text in each room is the same?

```
 @if (room.GuaranteePolicy == ? )
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>@room.GuaranteePolicy</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <th>
            <span>@room.GuaranteePolicy</span>
         </th>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out if all rooms have the same `GuaranteePolicy` property value, you should prepare *ViewModel* with that information and send it to the *View* afterwards.

Simplified room class:

```
public class Room
{
    public string GuaranteePolicy { get; set; }
}
```

Loginc inside your controller that returns View in which you are displaying information:

```
List<Room> rooms = GetSelectedRooms(); //example

bool samePolicy = false;
var firstRoom = rooms.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstRoom != null)
{
    samePolicy = rooms.All(r => r.GuaranteePolicy == firstRoom.GuaranteePolicy);
}

//Attach samePolicy onto ViewModel or ViewBag so you can use it inside Razor view
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller make a function that check if all the rooms have the same Policy and assign a property in the model to true or false  :

```
public class RoomsModel{
public bool SamePolicy ...
public .......  Rooms ...
}
```

Then check if this property true in the cshtml

```
if(Model.SamePolicy){
<footer>....
 }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. So have would you implement your suggestion with the `@GuaranteePolicy` mergefield? I am getting quite confused where to set that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100 percent sure if I understood your question correctly, but in a nutshell, you want to check the following: your model consists of multiple bookings, each of which may or may not have `GuaranteePolicy`. You want to check that if they are set, then they are all the same, and render the footer only if this is true. You could solve it like the following:

```
@{
    string firstGuaranteePolicy = Model.Bookings.Select(b => b.GuaranteePolicy).FirstOrDefault();
    bool areAllTheSame = Model.Bookings.Select(b => b.GuaranteePolicy).All(val => val == firstGuaranteePolicy);
}

@if (areAllTheSame)
{
    <tfoot>
    ...
    </tfoot>
}
```

So simply you extract the first `GuaranteePolicy` value (I assume you can navigate to them through a property `Bookings`, modify that according to your model structure), and if all of them are the same as the first one, then all of them are identical.